# AWS Elasticache redis sudden slowness

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

Having an issue where suddenly my aws redis cluster suddenly starts to suffer. Retrieve and save time suddenly jumps from milliseconds to hundreds of seconds. The size of the data stored and retrieved has slightly gone up, but not enough to justify this level of performance drop. We noticed network packets in also spike, not sure why. Replication lag goes from 0 to 5 minutes. And this is very sudden.. Happens in the span of a minute.

More confusing, we have some ec2 IIS instances in 3 availability zones. Our redis is in A and B. Instances are in A B and C. The instances in C all spike to 100% CPU at the same time as redis going belly up. Only those in avail zone C. I don't know if this is the cause of redis going belly up, or an effect, or unrelated.

Any assistance appreciated. Redis is knew to me and being in aws, there is limited access to diagnose it. I think. Thanks all!

Comment: I should also add that cache misses drastically jump at the same time.

Comment: Did you check hardware metrics? Like CPU usage (something running along redis, starving resources), memory usage (is it swapping on hardrive, for instance, during a VM snapshot or a database snapshot? Redis HATES swapping), and network usage (downloading lots of data from the instance which slows down the redis requests?) ?

Comment: No swap appears to be in use. CPU hits 22% which I understand is the limit since its single threaded.